# IAM user created from cli not showing up in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I created an IAM user using the the CLI and it does not show up in the console. I installed the CLI and ran:

```
$ aws iam create-user --user-name Connor  
$ aws iam create-access-key --user-name Connor
```

When I login to the AWS console with administrator access and navigate to the IAM section, no user named "Connor" shows up. However, when I run:

```
$ aws iam list-users                          
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "UserName": "Connor", 
            "Path": "/", 
            "CreateDate": "2017-08-02T19:08:54Z", 
            "UserId": "XXXXXXXXX", 
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:user/Connor"
        }, 
        {
            "UserName": "connor11528", 
            "Path": "/", 
            "CreateDate": "2017-03-11T19:30:43Z", 
            "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXX", 
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:user/connor11528"
        }
    ]
}
```

The user Connor is there but a not some IAM users that show up in the console. Why does the Connor IAM user not show up on the console?

Comment: The credentials in `~/.aws/config` are for a different AWS account?

Answer (score 1):

Run this CLI to query to get the account number of the credentials configured for CLI:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query 'SecurityGroups[0].OwnerId' --output text
```

This account number has to be different from the one you see on the AWS console. Make sure you use the correct account credentials.